# How to aggregate data depending on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

at the moment I try to transform some data within a dataframe and I am struggling somehow. I start with a minimal example of my initial situation:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'UUID': ['UUID1','UUID2','UUID3','UUID3'],
        'grouping': ['a','a','a','b'],
        'code': ['1','2','3','4']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

>     UUID grouping code
>  0  UUID1        a    1
>  1  UUID2        a    2
>  2  UUID3        a    3
>  3  UUID3        b    4
```

I have a UUID and want to transform the table in a way that I have only unique UUIDs in a column. The grouping column should be used to swap the code values to the new cols. Here is an output of a dataframe I would like to receive:

```
>     UUID  code a  code b
>  0  UUID1      1    NaN
>  1  UUID2      2    NaN
>  2  UUID3      3      4
```

I tried to work with `pd.crosstab()` and `pd.getdummies()` but both did not do the job.

I am happy for any help I can get :-).

Best P

Comment: You are looking for a `pivot`. The dup has a lot of information, but essentially: `df.pivot(index='UUID', columns='grouping', values='code')`

Comment: thanks :-), i should have known that :-)